# Unable to find liferay Articles by category via JSON

Tags: java, json, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to locate `liferay` articles by category through `JSONWS` services.  I am able to find the correct `Vocabulary`, then the `Categories` under that `Vocabulary`, but I cannot determine how to actually use that information in any other APIs.

I have looked through all the `JournalArticle` calls and nothing references any kind of `Vocabulary` or `Category` parameter.  Google shows how to retrieve [the categories off the article](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10984882) via java.

I cannot find a way to get the articles categories via JSON calls.  Why are the `Category` and `Vocabulary` information missing from the JSON apis?

Comment: Another option would be to use Tags in this as well, but the same problem arises. There is no clear way to find Assets with certain Tags on them through the JSONWS.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known fact that Liferay doesn't expose all local services to the JSON api. Therefore we usually create our own REST servlet containing the necessary methods. It is very easy to create these kinds of servlets with Spring and you have full control over which API you want to provide...